# Regex match any combination of two characters

Tags: regex, google-sheets, wildcard

I'm trying to remove extra wildcard characters from a string but am having a bit of trouble. If there are any combination of `?` or `*`, I want to replace it with a `*`. For example I want to simplify

```
"*?a?s?*?k?i?n?a?r?d?*?*?d?e?d?i?c?a?t?e?d?*?r?e?g?i?o?n?a?l*"
```

to

```
"*a?s*k?i?n?a?r?d*d?e?d?i?c?a?t?e?d*r?e?g?i?o?n?a?l*"
```

In Google sheets, I am using the `REGEXREPLACE` function and can get part of the way there.

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\?\*)+","*")

"*?a?s*?k?i?n?a?r?d*?d?e?d?i?c?a?t?e?d*?r?e?g?i?o?n?a?l*"
```

However, reading other threads it seems like I have to use `|` somehow to allow for either `*?` or `?*`. But all the `?`'s are removed when I try and add it in.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you tell us the regex you used when you tried to "add it in"?

Comment: I tried to use the expression `(\?|\*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\?\*|\*\?)+(\*|\?)?","*")
```

The crucial part here is to take unbalanced "pairs" like `?*?` with an optional `?` into account. But we must not forget the balanced pairs.

An important part about [alternations](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) is to sort them from long to short to avoid double, triple, etc. `*` in the result - but this does not apply here.

---

It is not mentioned in the question, but if there are also multiples of a sign allowed we could use a pattern like this with a general regex engine: [`(?:\?\*|\*\?|(\*|\?)\1)+(\*|\?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/GxG3yV/1)

However, this is not possible with `REGEXREPLACE` in Google Sheets. Instead, we could chain replace those cases.

Comment: that replaces all the `?` with `*`

Comment: The result still has `*?` - `"*a?s*?k?i?n?a?r?d*?d?e?d?i?c?a?t?e?d*?r?e?g?i?o?n?a?l*"`. That's because there are instances of `?*?`...

Comment: I think you meant `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\?\*\??|\??\*\?)+","*")`, because right now the 2 options in parenthesis are not balanced.

Comment: @AntoineColson Thanks. However, the second case should handle another unbalanced case, `*?*`,  luckily there is no such case.

Comment: True! there is no such case in OP's example, but it's just an example ;) so I guess the best would be this then: `=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\?\*\??|\??\*\?)|\??\*\?|\?\*\??)+","*")`

Comment: @AntoineColson thanks for pushing me. I did some more tests and expanded the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\?*\*[?*]*","*")`

Basically, any sequence of ?s and *s with at least one *.

Comment: Nice, but does not work for extended cases like this `*?a?s?*?k?i?n?a?r?d?*?*?d?e?d?i?c?a?t?e?d?*?****r?e?g????i?o?n?a?l*`

Comment: The question was a little sparse in its validation cases, but I interpreted it to mean the user wanted to remove superfluous Google Sheets wildcards in favor of single asterisks where logically equivalent ("If there are any combination of ? or *, I want to replace it with a *"). You may have a different interpretation, but to that end I believe this pattern works for your case: https://regex101.com/r/q3L4zV/1

Comment: Unfortunately, the guidance is often not very clear and the case has been settled.

Answer (score 0):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[\?\*]{2,}","*")
```

Any combinations:2 or more of {`?`,`*`} will be replaced by `*`